# Magento 2, overriding module sales js

Tags: magento2, module, sales, requirejs

In order to override the `Magento_Sales/web/order/create/scripts.js` I created `MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js`. After removing `_requirejs` from `pub/static` and doing the deploying, I realized modification I made are not in new file created in `_requirejs`. What have I missed?

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Sales/web/order/create/scripts.js':
                'MyVendor_myModule/web/order/create/scripts.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: put your js file in '`MyVendor_myModule/web/js/order/create/scripts.js'` then check

Comment: should I edit the above also?

Comment: yes update it above as well

Comment: You don't need to pass `.js` extension there just leave only name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following way

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts': {
                'MyVendor_myModule/js/order/create/scriptUpdate': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

OR

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts": "MyVendor_myModule/js/order/create/scripts",
        }
    }
}
```

In that case your overwrite js location

```
MyVendor/myModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/order/create/scripts.js
```

Comment: One question, can I name it scriptUpdate.js? Or it has to be same name?MyVendor/myModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/order/create/scriptUpdate.js

Comment: Yes, you can. Follow step one. I just updated answer, check now.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep here updated

Comment: Have you an idea about how to override `_calcProductPrice` function in custom `scripts.js` file (using mixins)?

Answer (score 3):

Issue with the **location of the js file** :

Try with below code :

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts": "MyVendor_myModule/js/order/create/scripts",
        }
    }
}
```

Js file location should be :

> **Vendorname/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/order/create/scripts.js**

Answer (score 0):

Use custom JavaScript (see Below Link)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html